# How to add a prefix - suffix to a node title from a module

Tags: theming

I loaded a renderable array within a hook_block_view.  I need to add a prefix and suffix to the title before rendering it. How can I manage to do that ?

Comment: are we talking about nodes or blocks here?

Comment: well, i'm displaying nodes into a block and I need to add classes to their title

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the very title. Adding prefixes and suffixes is not a job for a module. You do it in template. If you need to wrap it in html tags, do it in `node.tpl.php`. If you need some more elaborated logic, see [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7).

Comment: I understand but when looking at the available variables in [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) we can find $title_prefix and $title_suffix that are supposed to be populated by modules. How can I popolate it ?

Answer (score 1):

In hook_preprocess_node($variables) set $variables['title_prefix'] = 'test';

Answer (score 0):

locate the title in question, and add the prefix and suffix as you do in a form like this:

```
$array['the_title']['#prefix'] = "<div class='wrapper'>";
$array['the_title']['#suffix'] = "</div>";
```

Hope it helps